# PHP Open_SSL issue docusign SOAP call

Tags: docusignapi

We are using docusign SOAP PHP SDK provided on github from link below:

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/tree/master/PHP

Now docusign do have a way to sign API calls using X.509 certificate, issue is when we parse our PEM file it throws:
"openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key"

Specifically file:

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/blob/master/PHP/DocuSignSample/api/APIService.php

From line number 2236 to 2247 is where we've to pass our PEM file to get things working after removing comments. But we were getting continuously one error "openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key"

We tried getting in touch with Docusign team, they say PHP is wrong but we are using versions and libraries they've mentioned. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be missing the line to load the key.

```
/* load the private key from file - last arg is bool if key in file (TRUE) or is string (FALSE) */
$objKey->loadKey('filename_of_private_key.pem', true);
```